# Issue on Scroll To Section

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using jQuery and Bootstrap 3 I am trying to create a one page Scrolling Website. Here is the  <kbd>**[Working Demo](http://www.homecares.ca/scrool/)**</kbd> . So far it looks fine when user scrolls in sequence like from `Section 1` to `Section 2` or `Section 2`to `Section 3` but I have some issue on `nav navbar-nav` items **when user scrolls out of order** like from `Section 1` to `Section 6`. It looks like `nav navbar-nav` steps on each items to get the target item!(As you can see in following image)

**There is also one other important** issue on `Section 7` scrolling. which it not scrolls to the same positions as  other sections and there is more space. (As you can see in following image)

[image]

Here is the jquery which I used for Scrolling

```
<script>
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Can you please help me to fix these thing on the code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) The problem with the last section should be ease to fix. There is not enought "room" underneath the last section and so the browser cannot scroll any further. A quick and dirty fix for that would be to insert some

```
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

lines at the end of the last paragraph.

2) I think this could be tricky. The problem is that not the Sections, but the "html" and "body" elements are scrolled. That means if the user is at the first section and clicks on the last section the whole page is scrolled. The user sees all content during the scroll animation. I think that is how it is supposed to work. Otherwise you would have to change how and what you actually scroll.

Comment: Thanks Preli, so what is the solution?